# Finding a flat plane within iPhone depth data

Tags: mathematics, depth-map

I have real time depth data coming from an iPhone and I want to identify flat objects within the point cloud so that I can highlight the Hard edges in the images. The objects can be at any angle and I'm only looking for flat faces.

I'm not a math expert and just looking for ways that this could be done relatively easily so just looking for pointers to relevant algorithms that could achieve this.

ty

Comment: take a look at this: https://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/pdfs/Yang2010Plane.pdf

Comment: so a very common methodology is RANSAC...  it is as well easy to implement. I've a question... how fast should these planes be calculated? what are you planing to do? How good does the outcoming planes need to be (precise)?

Comment: Any segmentation algorithm sounds like it would do the job. You can run some kind of edge preserving denoising (e.g. Perona-Malik), and then form the segmentation on the result.

Comment: Thanks guys. I’m trying to get as close to real-time as possible. Needs to be fairly accurate and the corner points May need to be guessed for one or two points as the items will be handheld so partly occluded.